# Sequential number of polygon vertices by Y coordinate value

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, modelbuilder, vertices

I have a shapefile of polygon parcels. Each parcel has a unique id called `propertyno.` I need to label the vertices of my polygons clockwise sequentially, starting at the most northern vertex in alphabetically order (A,B,C,D,E...).

I came across this tool (http://ianbroad.com/arcgis-toolbox-create-points-at-corners-of-polygon-with-arcpy/) from a [previous thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132797/how-to-generate-points-on-corner-of-polygon-only) which will identify corner vertices only and label them NW/NE/SW/SE,etc. The trouble is that it sometimes skips corners as my polygons are not all square. Some polygons have 4 vertices, some have up to 30. Additionally which vertex is the origin vertex will change depending on the orientation of my shapefile. It's not always the NW corner.

I am using ArcGIS 10.6 ModelBuilder and have thus far done the following steps:

- converted polygon features to vertices
- added x/y coordinates
- sorted the vertices based on `propertyno (order unimportant but used ascending)` and `POINT_Y`(descending, order is important)

Here is a screenshot of the attribute table of the sorted vertices.

[image]

I think what I need next in ModelBuilder or in Python code is to loop through the `propertyno` field, and for every polygon sequentially number the rows based on how many there are. Then start again for the next propertyno set of points.

I am a beginner coder and have not used iterations at all in ModelBuilder. The process I have in ModelBuilder so far is to take my polygon layer, create a points layer from the vertices, add the X/Y coordinates. Add a text "VERTEX_ID" field where the letter value for the point will go, and sort the points based on a polygon ID field (propertyno) and by the Y Coord. I still need to delete duplicate vertices (the first/last of the closed polygon is the same) and to do some sort of insert cursor to alphabetically label the points.

[image]

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: If you're wanting to tag this with ArcPy, then please include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried so far.  If you're wanting to tag this with ModelBuilder, then please include a test model that illustrates what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a screenshot of Modelbuilder of what I've tried so far.

Comment: Pls eloborate bit more about how you want sequential number. Based on Y value means..you want sequance to start from left to right ?